# Unsupported record type Exception : OrientDb, Gremlin, Java

Tags: java, gremlin, orientdb

I am using Groovy gremlin in my Java class to traverse orient-db and see the below issue. If I use :

```
g.V('@class','Person').has('city-name','NY').in('city-depends').toList()
```

I get the persons based on the city and If i try using transform to also get the friends of person using the edge friends

```
g.V('@class','Person').has('city-name','NY').in('city-  depends').transform({[it,it.in('friends').toList()]}).toList()
```

What I want is information of persons based in the city WITH their friends information (not only the edge id)

### Stacktrace:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Error on executing command: 

at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.handleException(OStorageRemote.java:1481)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.command(OStorageRemote.java:1059)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.command(OStorageRemoteThread.java:430)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:59)

at orientdb.prototype.OrientGremlinExample.getActivityByResource(OrientGremlinExample.java:87)

at orientdb.prototype.OrientGremlinExample.main(OrientGremlinExample.java:26)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported record type: 0

at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordFactoryManager.newInstance(ORecordFactoryManager.java:93)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryProtocol.readIdentifiable(OChannelBinaryProtocol.java:121)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.command(OStorageRemote.java:1023)

... 4 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record type '0' is not supported

at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordFactoryManager.getFactory(ORecordFactoryManager.java:108)

at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordFactoryManager.newInstance(ORecordFactoryManager.java:91)

... 6 more
```

### Code:

```
OGremlinHelper.global().create();

ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();

engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).put("g", graph);

OCommandGremlin command = new OCommandGremlin(" ...... ");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

List agg1 = graph.getRawGraph().command(command).execute(params);

System.out.println("Result:-- " + agg1);
```

Comment: I also read and used traverse in orientdb sql which would get the entire sun graph of the result set (with all edges and its attributes) is there any gremlin equivalent function to get results similar to that. Thanks !!

Comment: What release are you using? Please try 1.7-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: @Lvca Thanks for the response. I am using 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT of gremlin-java and 1.7-rc1 orient libraries.Please see the list :---                                      com.tinkerpop.gremlin - gremlin-java -2.5.0-SNAPSHOT,
com.orientechnologies-orient-commons-1.7-rc2,
com.orientechnologies-orientdb-core-1.7-rc2,
com.orientechnologies-orientdb-graphdb-1.7-rc2,
com.orientechnologies-orientdb-client-1.7-rc2,
com.orientechnologies-orientdb-object-1.7-rc2,
com.orientechnologies-orientdb-enterprise-1.7-rc2,

Comment: I see you're using rc2 not rc1. May you try with last 1.7-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Thanks @Lvca . I will try with 1.7-SNAPSHOT . But for now my priority is to get the performance numbers of orientdb with orientDbSQL . Help with also this will be greatly appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156580/mass-group-delete-orientdb-java